# Computing the partition-function of an exponential family member

Tags: probability, approximation, exponential-family

I am working on a Monte Carlo Expectation Propagation problem.

In that context I got the following property:

$
I =  \sum\limits_i w^{(i)} \log p_\eta(x^{(i)})
$

where $\{w^{(i)}\}_i$ are weights, $w^{(i)} \in [0,1] \forall i$ and $\sum\limits_i w^{(i)}=1$.
The probability $p_\eta(x)$ is a member of the exponential family

$
p_\eta(x) = Z(\eta) \exp\{\eta^T T(x)\}
$

with $T(.)$ being minimal. I don't know an analytic expression for $Z(\eta)$.

I want to differnetiate the term I  with respect to $\eta$.

**Now my question:**

How can I approximate $\log Z(\eta)$ so that the expression stays differentiable?

Comment: The first two derivatives of $\log [Z] $ wrt $\eta $ are the Expected value and variance of $T (x) $.  Not sure if that helps.

Comment: Well you can write the $\nabla_\eta \log Z_\eta = E_{p_\eta}[T(x)] = \mathbf{F} p_\eta$, the coefficients of the generalized Fourier series, cause T(x) is minimal...I think